# Testing for specific properties of rejected promises, with Mocha and Chai-as-Promised

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test the specifics of a rejected Promise, using [Chai-as-Promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/), [Mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha), and the "should" dialect. Promises are implemented by [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).

This works fine:

```
it('it should be rejected when given bad credentials', function () {

   var promiseOfUsers = db.auth("bad", "credentials").getUsers();
   return promiseOfUsers.should.eventually.be.rejectedWith(Error)

});
```

There is a "status" property on that error. I would like to assert that status is 401

This does not work:

```
it('it should be rejected when given bad credentials', function () {

   var promiseOfUsers = db.auth("bad", "credentials").getUsers();
   return promiseOfUsers.should.eventually.be.rejectedWith(Error)
       .that.has.property('status')
       .that.equals(401)

});
```

It seems that any attempt to assert without referencing "rejected" or rejectedWith(Error), fails and just prints the error out to the console.

**How can I delve into the reason for the rejection?**

Comment: Try `should.eventually.be.rejectedWith(Error).and.eventually.have.property("status").that.equals(401)`

Comment: thanks, but that didn't help. I will update the question to show the result.

Comment: Hmmm `.should.eventually.be.rejected.and.eventually.have.property("status").that.equals(401);` works but doesn't check the Error type. http://jsfiddle.net/F9SKD/

Comment: Meh. Personally I'd just do `.catch(function(err){ return err instanceof Error && error.status === 401});`

Comment: that does work with the minor correction "error.status" should be "err.status"

Comment: So if I understand well, there is no chai solution to test the error and the status in the same time?

Comment: My problem is slightly different, I need to test a custom field ("code") of the rejection Error AND the message too.. and I don't know how to do this with chai...

Answer (score 12):

I think rejectedWith() handler has some issues. But you can do like this:

`promiseOfUsers.should.be.rejected.and.eventually.have.property("status",401)`

Comment: It does have problems (v.5.3.0) see [Pull Request 123](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/issues/123) and [Pull Request 131](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/issues/131).
`return Promise.reject(2).should.be.rejectedWith(1);` passes when it should not...

Comment: Ah...adding the `eventually` in the second bit of chaining is what I was missing. Thanks! So this worked for me, which is that pattern I was trying to get to work: `promiseOfUsers.should.be.rejected.and.eventually.have.status(401)`. (With [chai-http](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/).)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to check if your promised was rejected **and check the resulting object (aka the reason)**:

```
return fooPromise.should.be.rejected.and.eventually.deep.equal({
   'x': 1,
   'y': 1,
   'z': 2
})
```

You can change `deep.equal` to the any of the usual other `chai` [matchers](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/).

*Note: This is an extension of @sertug's answer and hopefully will be useful for others coming here who looking for this.*