# Chai as Promised: `rejectWith` for particular error messages

Tags: chai-as-promised

I have a function that can return a few possible rejected promises:

```
Promise.reject({ a : 'x' })
//  or
Promise.reject({ b : 'y' })
// etc.
```

I want Chai as Promised to only pass this test if a particular rejection message is returned:

```
Promise.should.be.rejectedWith({ a : 'x'})
```

What I have found is that there is no difference between

```
fooPromise.should.be.rejectedWith({ a : 'x'})
```

and

```
fooPromise.should.be.rejectedWith({ foo : 'bar'})
```

Any rejection will satisfy either of these `rejectedWith` tests.

Is there a way to specify the rejection body so the test will only pass if that body is returned in the rejected promise under test?  I'm using Chai-as-promised 6.0.0.
Thank you

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37072092/1007926
Thank you James Lawson!